# Python every call to write outputs a number to the screen

Tags: python-3.x

Every call to `write` outputs a number to the screen (see below). How do I stop it?

The following code

```
Lines = ["This is line A\n", "This is line B\n", "This is line C\n"]

with open('Example.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in Lines:
        file_out.write(line)
```

results in

```
15
15
15
```

printed to the screen.

Comment: This worked properly for me not sure where that issue might be coming from. Is there any more to the code your trying?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the output of `file_out.write(line)` to a variable:

```
Lines = ["This is line A\n", "This is line B\n", "This is line C\n"]

with open('Example.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in Lines:
        _ = file_out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `writelines` instead of a for loop. I ran this code and didn't have any output to the console.

```py
Lines = ["This is line A\n", "This is line B\n", "This is line C\n"]

with open('Example.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    file_out.writelines(Lines)
```

Comment: This seems to append to a file, rather than write a new one.

Comment: Not to be contrary, but that behaviour is determined by the second argument to `open()`. `'w'` overwrites the file, while `'a'` appends to the file.

Comment: Sorry, I still used in the `for` loop, so it wrote 3 times.

Comment: So why does `write` prints to the screen and `writelines` doesn't?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I can't replicate it in Python 3.6.3.